# ¿Cómo integro una BD sqlite a mi proyecto java?

Tags: java, netbeans, sqlite

tengo una duda, hice un crud en NetBeans con java, y le coloque una BD usando sqliteadministrador,
así la conecte

```
public class conexion {
String strConexionDB ="jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Mercadeo Eforsalud/Documents/Desktop/bd/inscripciones.s3db";
Connection conn = null;
public conexion(){
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(strConexionDB);
        System.out.println("conexion establecida");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("conexion fallida"+e);

    }

};
```

lo que quiero es poder retirar la url de la BD osea la dirección para poder hacer portable el programa, agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Coloca el string en una variable de entorno y accede a ella usando `System.getenv("NOMBRE_DE_LA_VARIABLE");`

Comment: me podrías decir como seria o algún video es que soy nuevo en esto, lo siento